# Spring + Thymeleaf type Converter in a form

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm trying to use a type converter in a Spring boot app and using Thymeleaf but I can't get it working. I've put some code on Github so you can see exactly what I'm trying to do. This is Spring 1.5.1 and Thymeleaf 3.0.3. https://github.com/matthewsommer/spring-thymeleaf-simple-converter

Basically this code is just trying to add a person to a comment object. The person object is null when it gets posted and I don't understand why.

Something that's odd is that the ID of the person isn't being added to the value attribute but it is if th:field="*{body}" is removed. I think it has to do with this: https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/495 but I'm currently trying to add BindingResult and it's not working...

My HTML is:

```
<body>
<div th:if="${personObject != null}" th:text="${personObject.name}"></div>
<form th:action="@{/}" th:object="${comment}" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" th:if="${personObject != null}" th:value="${personObject.id}" th:field="*{person}" />
    <textarea id="comment" placeholder="Comment..." th:field="*{body}"></textarea>
    <button id="comment_submit" type="submit">Comment</button>
</form>
<div th:text="${comment.body}"></div>
</body>
```

My controller:

```
@Controller
public class HomeWebController {

  @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String getHome(final HttpServletRequest request, final Map<String, Object> model, @ModelAttribute(value = "comment") Comment comment) {
model.put("personObject", new Person(1, "John Smith"));
return "Home";
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public String postHome(final HttpServletRequest request, final Map<String, Object> model, @ModelAttribute(value = "comment") Comment comment) {
model.put("commentBody", comment.getBody());
model.put("person", comment.getPerson());
return "Home";
  }

}
```

And the converter:

```
@Component
public class StringToPersonConverter implements Converter<String, Person> {

  @Autowired
  public StringToPersonConverter() { }

  @Override
  public Person convert(String id) {
if(id == "1") {
  Person person = new Person(1, "John Smith");
  return person;
}
return null;
  }
    }
```

Comment: did you tried the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi finally I had to do some changes to make it work, but this is the result class by class.

ConvertorApplication:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class ConvertorApplication extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConvertorApplication.class, args);
    }

    //Add converter and configuration annotation
    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        registry.addConverter(new StringToPersonConverter());
    }
}
```

StringToPersonConverter:

```
@Override
public Person convert(String id) {
    //Never compare String with == use equals, the "==" compares memory space not the values 
    if(id.equals("1")) {
      Person person = new Person(1, "John Smith");
      return person;
    }
    return null;
}
```

HomeWebController

```
@Controller
public class HomeWebController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getHome(final Map<String, Object> model, @ModelAttribute(value = "comment") Comment comment) {
        //Initialize the comment with the person inside, no need of personObject object
        model.put("comment", new Comment(new Person(1, "John Smith")));
        return "Home";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String postHome(final Map<String, Object> model,
                           @ModelAttribute(value = "comment") Comment comment,
                           @RequestParam(value = "person.id") Person person) {
        //from the view retrieve the value person.id which will be used by the converter to build the Person entity
        comment.setPerson(person);
        model.put("comment", comment);
        return "Home";
    }
}
```

Comment (Add empty constructor)

```
public Comment(){}
```

Person (Add empty constructor)

```
public Person(){}
```

Home.jsp (Basically remove personObject, not need)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="//www.thymeleaf.org">
<body>
    <div th:text="${comment.person.name}"></div>
    <form th:action="@{/}" th:object="${comment}" method="post">
        <input type="hidden"  th:field="*{person.id}" />
        <textarea id="comment" placeholder="Comment..." th:field="*{body}"></textarea>
        <button id="comment_submit" type="submit">Comment</button>
    </form>
    <div th:text="${comment.body}"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

That's would be everything to make it work.

Comment: Is there now way to have Spring set the person to comment without having to do it in the controller? If the input is in the form object I feel like it would be nice for comment.person to be set directly from the inputs on the html.

Comment: Maybe you can receive an userId in the GET method, then set the User to the new comment, and make it more generic, but I think the cleaner way to setup the user is in the controller method